# meteor infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm attempting to alter the attributes of a Collection to give them an absolute position before rendering. If the item is first in the collection, it's given a top of 0, and a left of 0. Second is given a top of 0, and a left of 20, etc. But when I try to build this logic into my template, it results in an infinite loop. Here's my code:

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {

  _.extend(Template.movies, {

    movies: function() {
      var movies = Movies.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});

      var determineLocation = function(){
        console.log('hello');

          var count = 0; 

            movies.forEach(function(movie){
              // do some math
              Movies.update(movie._id, {$set: {left: 10, top: 20}});
              count++; 
            });
          }; 

      determineLocation(); 

      return movies; 
    }
  });
};
```

I think it's doing this because the Movies.update command triggers the movies function to render again, thus resulting in the infinite loop. How should I get around this? Where is the proper location to put the determineLocation function?

Comment: Also I've been blogging and ran into a case of infinite looping, which I isolated the rendering, take a look a doctormehmet dot blogspot dot com if you think it might help.  I don't use startup there, instead I use autorun, but the case is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

You want this code to run a single time when the client first loads? I think a `Meteor.startup` call is appropriate:

```
 Meteor.startup(function() {
   // do the updating part
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your meteor extension inside of the startup Meteor startup function:

```
Meteor.startup( function(){
if (Meteor.is_client) {

  _.extend(Template.movies, {

    movies: function() {
    var movies = Movies.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});

    var determineLocation = function(){
    console.log('hello');

    var count = 0; 

    movies.forEach(function(movie){
          // do some math
          Movies.update(movie._id, {$set: {left: 10, top: 20}});
          count++; 
        });
      }; 

      determineLocation(); 

      return movies; 
    }
  });
};
```

The startups are more or less merged, so no worries.